# Can I have files automatically be added to my MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a custom search function on my site, using PHP. I don't like having to go to my database every time I make a page, so can I write something to automatically add a new page to my database? Here's my code:

```
    <?php

    $k = $_GET['k'];

    $terms = explode(" ", $k);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";


    foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;

        if ($i == 1)
            $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        else
            $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }

    //connect
    mysql_connect("*****", "*****", "*****");
    mysql_select_db("*****");   

    $query = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows > 0){

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $keywords = $row['keywords'];
            $link = $row['link'];

            echo "<h3><a href='$link'>$title</a></h3>

                <hr />";
        }

    }
    else 
        echo "No Results Found for \"<b>$k</b>\". Try Again.";


    //disconnect
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Erm--what? There's not even an insert in the above code, so what exactly are you adding to the database?

Comment: This just my sample code. When I add a page into my databse so I can search for it on my site, I have to put in the link, the title, and the keywords. I want to be able to do all this automatically without going to the database.

Comment: The answer is yes, everything is possible. But we need to know a bit more about how your system currently works and how its built. So we can advise you the best course of action.

Comment: I don't understand that part : "I don't like having to go to my database every time I make a page, so can I write something to automatically add a new page to my database?". Hum, add page to a database ?